# Drop a column when using renderTable

Tags: r, shiny

```
output$Table <- 
    renderTable(
      myData()%>%mutate(searchmatch<-str_extract(DocumentText,"([^\\s]+\\s){50}to treat(\\s[^\\s]+){50}"))
     )
```

This final section of my code searches 'DocumentText' for a character string and adds it into a new column.
I would like to drop the 'DocumentText' column after the new column is added as it is very large, I have tried using select(myData,-DocumentText) but this didn't work. I also tried using myData([-2],) bu this also failed;
Any suggestions would be great

Comment: What object is `myData`? Is it a function? If it is a dataframe, then `myData[-2]` or `myData[, -2]`

Comment: myData is a dataframe

Comment: Please add a reproducible example so that you are more likely to get help from others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively, have you tried

```
output$Table <- 
    renderTable(
      myData() %>% 
      mutate(searchmatch = str_extract(DocumentText,"([^\\s]+\\s){50}to 
      treat(\\s[^\\s]+){50}")) %>% 
      select(-DocumentText)
     )
```